# voice classification api for android

Tags: android

I want to develop an android application which interacts with the user using voice. I looked at google's speech to text API at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html

I could not find anything which provides a classification service.
Recognition is much more difficult than classification.
In my usecase, my app will give user the options(eg: say left or right). So, instead of solving the harder of problem of what recognizing what the user said, I only need to decide whether he/she said left or right. I believe that the currrent state of the art in speech classification can solve the latter binary-classification problem with almost 99% accuracy.

Is their an API which is optimized for classifying voice into few(2-3) classes(words/phrases), rather than full blown recognition?

(I have significant Java/C++/machine learning experience, but no android experience)

(recognition, as described above can also be viewed as classification into infinitely many sentences ; hence it is a harder problem(2 vs countably-infinite classes))

Answer (score 0):

This [Nuance API](http://dragonmobile.nuancemobiledeveloper.com/public/index.php?task=home) may help you, This is the [list](http://dragonmobile.nuancemobiledeveloper.com/public/index.php?task=supportedPlatforms#android) of supported devices